# How to get a list of the last uploaded videos from a YouTube channel?

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have a Youtube channel and am trying to develop an android app that will list the videos of my channel in a chronological order. I'm using the YouTube API. But, I do not know how to get the entire list of last uploaded videos at once. How can I do that in Android? Is that even possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check this URL that retrieves the latest videos from a channel :

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?key={your_key_here}&channelId={channel_id_here}&part=snippet,id&order=date&maxResults=20
```

Comment: Thanks. But, how can I work with this URL on Android? It retrieves the latest videos but where the results are saved? I have no idea!

Comment: useful for youtube api tutorial [link](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/12/how-to-play-youtube-video-in-android-app/) or [sample project](https://github.com/francoj11/Android-Youtube-NatGeo)